# Diagram: Troubles with axis labels

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to hide the label (number) of  "extra y ticks=  {2.5}". The number should not be shown on the diagram. In addition to this i dont want the whole line at this point. I just want a small mark.

Sorry for my English i hope you can understand my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,height=10cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar sampled,
    colorbar style={samples=13},
    grid=both,
    scale only axis=true,
    width=10cm,
    height=15cm,
    xtick={0,1,...,10},
    ytick={-8,-7,...,10},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-8,
    ymax=8,
    extra y ticks=  {2.5}
    ]

\addplot[
    scatter,mark=text, text mark={\rule{14mm}{5mm}},only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
    ]
    table {
    x y color myvalue
    2 3 1 100
    4 3 2 3
    2 7 3 0.75
    7 7 4 45
    8 5 2 3
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `extra y tick labels={}` to remove the label

Comment: And you can use `extra y tick style={grid=none}` to remove the grid line at the extra y tick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
extra y tick labels={},
extra y tick style={grid=none}
```

to remove the label and the grid lines for `extra y ticks`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- current version is 1.14

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,height=10cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar sampled,
    colorbar style={samples=13},
    grid=both,
    scale only axis=true,
    width=10cm,
    height=15cm,
    xtick={0,1,...,10},
    ytick={-8,-7,...,10},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-8,
    ymax=8,
    extra y ticks=  {2.5},
    extra y tick labels={},% <- added
    extra y tick style={grid=none}% <- added
    ]

\addplot[
    scatter,mark=text, text mark={\rule{14mm}{5mm}},only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
    ]
    table {
    x y color myvalue
    2 3 1 100
    4 3 2 3
    2 7 3 0.75
    7 7 4 45
    8 5 2 3
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I would suggest to set a value for option `compat` as the first pgfplots key in the document.